# How can I turn this script to a function

Tags: matlab, function

I am new to Matlab or any kind of programming language for that matter and I am trying to turn this script to a function i want the function to return x and u(x,t), I've tried different ways but the plot doesn't work like it does on the script

```
matlab code:
xmin=0;
xmax=1;
N=100;
dt=0.009;
t=0;
%tmax=0.5;
v=1;

%--------------% discrétiser le domaine --------------------------

dx=(xmax-xmin)/N;
x=xmin-dx : dx : xmax+dx;

%--------------% initialiser les conditions-----------------------

u0=exp(-200*(x-0.25).^2);
u=u0;
unpl=u0;

%--------------% Écouler le temps---------------------------------

%nsteps=tmax/dt;

while t < 1.0
%--------------% calculate boundary conditions-------------

u(1)=u(3);
u(N+3)=u(N+1);

%--------------% la solution numérique Upwind ------------------

for i=2 : N+2
unpl(i)=u(i)-v*(dt/dx)*(u(i)-u(i-1));
end

%---------------% mise à jour de t------------------------------

   t=t+dt;
   u=unpl;

  %----------------% plot solution----------------------------------

 plot(x,u,'bo-','markerfacecolor','b')
   hold on
   hold off
 xlabel('x','fontsize',16)
 ylabel('u(t,x)','fontsize',16)
 title(sprintf('time=%1.3f',t),'fontsize',16)
 shg
 pause(dt);
 end
```

Comment: what i tried is to put function x=upwindU (xmin, xmax) and removed the itinial value of xmin and xmax i did the same for unpl,sorry i didnt include it in my question but the code wasnt that diffrent so i didnt want to post something repetitive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it would be as follows:

1.First, Create a new file which should be named according to your function name. In my case I chose the name 'func' but it should be more indicative:

```
function [ x,u ] = func(xmin,xmax,N,dt,t,v)

dx=(xmax-xmin)/N;
x=xmin-dx : dx : xmax+dx;

u0=exp(-200*(x-0.25).^2);
u=u0;
unpl=u0;


while t < 1.0
    u(1)=u(3);
    u(N+3)=u(N+1);

    for i=2 : N+2
        unpl(i)=u(i)-v*(dt/dx)*(u(i)-u(i-1));
    end

    t=t+dt;
    u=unpl;

    plot(x,u,'bo-','markerfacecolor','b')
    hold on
    hold off
    xlabel('x','fontsize',16)
    ylabel('u(t,x)','fontsize',16)
    title(sprintf('time=%1.3f',t),'fontsize',16)
    shg
    pause(dt);
end

end
```

2.A call to this function could be done as follows:

```
xmin=0;
xmax=1;
N=100;
dt=0.009;
t=0;
v=1;
[ x,u ] = func(xmin,xmax,N,dt,t,v);
```

Comment: thank you that helped so much,only one probleme when i try to trun the function into a java package it seems to generate an illegal unicode escape error any idea what i can change to fix it?

Comment: the second question is unclear. I suggest opening another question with more details regarding to the problem which you are facing